# Php echo a row values by unique code and email

Tags: php, mysql

In my website I'm having **AGENT AND CUSTOMER** so The agent role is to **fill the application for the user**, And the user has to **login with details** given by AGENT verify and submit, so if a user login with **EMAIL AND RANDOM-CODE**, The **Details of the user should ECHO on the input field**.Please Help me, Thanks in Advance.

AGENT FILLED THE FORM AND SAVED IN DB:

Consider My Database Has:

```
Id     name     email       country      zip     Phone      Random-Code
1     kalyan   xxxx@yy.com  California  77777    999999       ABCDEF
```

So Here AGENT will GENERATE LOGIN DETAILS HAS **EMAIL AND RANDOM-CODE**

CUSTOMER LOGIN:

```
    EMAIL: xxxx@yy.com

    CODE:  ABCDEF

        LOGIN
```

When the Customer Login with The above Email and code The details of that Customer Should Echo.

Output should be:

```
                                                      RANDOM-CODE: ABCDEF

Firstname: kalyan                   E-mail: xxxx@yy.com

Country:   California               zipcode: 77777

Phone:    999999

                           SUBMIT
```

LOGIN CODE FOR CUSTOMER'S:

```
<form action="?p=login&t=loginsubmit" method="post" >
    <div class="login">
        <?php
  if $_REQUEST['msg']
?>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-  hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>  </button><strong>Warning!!! E-MAIL OR PASSWORD IS WRONG...</strong></div> <?php }?><h2 style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 45px; color: black;">CUSTOMER LOGIN</h2><br><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="loanid" required=""><br><br><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="code" name="code" id="dob" required=""><br><br><br>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" style="position: relative; left: 4px; width: 250px;">LOGIN</button>
    </div>
    </form>

               <?php function loginmonitor($email,$code) {
               $query=mysql_query("select * from loanapp where email='$email' and code='$code'");
                $query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                $dbid=$query_row['id'];
                if(empty($dbid)){?><script>document.location='?msg=not a  valid user&p=login';</script><?php}}
```

**I Tried This But No OUTPUT AS ABOVE:**

> $code = $_POST['code'];
>   $email = $_POST['email'];
>
> $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, mobileno FROM `loanapp` WHERE code = ? AND email = ?");
>   $sql->execute(array($code, $email));
>   $results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
>
> foreach ($results as $row) {
>
> echo $row['firstname'].'
> ';
>   echo $row['lastname'].'
> ';
>   echo $row['mobileno'].'
> ';
>
> }

So what is the Exact Query should be Used to Fetch this. Help me Out, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen                                                                          $code = $_POST['code'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, mobileno FROM `clients` WHERE code = ? AND email = ?");
$sql->execute(array($code, $email));
 $results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 foreach ($results as $row) {

  echo $row['firstname'].'<br>';
  echo $row['lastname'].'<br>';
 echo $row['mobileno'].'<br>';

 }

Comment: where is the login code and how user is going to login ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: @Renier customer login is working but echoing details not working shows Empty page.

Comment: Have you checked for errors? i.e. check your browsers console for error, etc.

Comment: @Renier i checked but i cant find anything.